# Count value and missing FK in one pass

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to get value and null count in one pass when null is absent FK.
Can the query below be reduced to a single select?
Or some other form that is more efficient.
The first is what I am calling the null count.

PK on docSVsys is sID
PK on docSVtext is sID, fieldID with a FK to docSVsys

```
select top 1000 [value], [COUNT] 
from 
(
    select NULL as [value], COUNT(*) as [count] 
      from [docSVsys] with (nolock) 
      left join [docSVtext] with (nolock) 
        on [docSVtext].[sID] = [docSVsys].[sID] 
       and [docSVtext].[fieldID] = 101 
     where [docSVtext].[sID] is null
  union 
    select [value], COUNT(*) as [count]  
      from [docSVtext] with (nolock)   
     where [fieldID] = 101 
     group by [value]  
) as  [ccount] 
order by [COUNT] desc
```

If [docSVtext] only has a few thousand unique values then this is pretty efficient
And that is the typical scenario
But [docSVtext] can also have over a million unique values and cannot use top or sort in the union

I think I have a better query

```
select top 1000 ISNULL([docSVtext].[value],'null'), COUNT(*)
  from [docSVsys] with (nolock) 
  left join [docSVtext] with (nolock) 
    on [docSVtext].[sID] = [docSVsys].[sID] 
   and [docSVtext].[fieldID] = 101 
  group by ISNULL([docSVtext].[value],'null')
  order by COUNT(*) desc
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `(fieldID, value)`?

Comment: @ypercube yes index on fieldID, value

Comment: Is it slow if you have only top 1000 and the second part of the union?

Comment: @ypercube Somehow I had it in my head that I could not use a top or order inside the union.

Comment: I said using only the second part, without `UNION`.

Comment: The first part is only one row so I think the main issue is sorting the second part (finding the top 1000 of a possibly million rows.)

Comment: Correct, smoking fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of the union is only one row so I think the main issue is sorting the second part (finding the top 1000 of a possibly million rows.)

So, try using `UNION ALL` and sorting in the second part of the union, keeping only the top 1000 rows (plus 1) for the second sort:

```
select top (1000) [value], [COUNT] 
from 
(
    select NULL as [value], COUNT(*) as [count] 
      from [docSVsys] with (nolock) 
      left join [docSVtext] with (nolock) 
        on [docSVtext].[sID] = [docSVsys].[sID] 
       and [docSVtext].[fieldID] = 101 
     where [docSVtext].[sID] is null
  union all
    select *
    from
    ( select top (1000)
             [value], COUNT(*) as [count]  
        from [docSVtext] with (nolock)   
       where [fieldID] = 101 
       group by [value]
       order by [count] desc 
    ) as x  
) as  [ccount] 
order by [COUNT] desc ;
```

---

You may also want to try this (improvement of your 2nd query). Not sure if it will return same results:

```
select top (1000)
       [docSVtext].[value], COUNT(*) as [count]
  from [docSVsys] with (nolock) 
  left join [docSVtext] with (nolock) 
    on [docSVtext].[sID] = [docSVsys].[sID] 
   and [docSVtext].[fieldID] = 101 
  group by [docSVtext].[value]
  order by [count] desc ;
```

Comment: I had it in my head that I could not do top or order inside the union.  I did try but I clearly had a syntax error.  This is about twice as efficient as the isnull that I posted.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't use top inside a union (you can but the results may not be what you expect because you can have have multiple `TOP` but only one `ORDER BY` in the `UNION`)